# Export data from 1 Foursquare account and import it to another one

Tags: export, import, foursquare

I see that there's "Export data" option (already requested it). However, is there a way to import it into a new Foursquare account?

Comment: Where do you see an export button?

Comment: @philgo20 IIRC it was in the account settings page, but I deleted my account an year ago & cannot confirm that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Foursquare doesn't support importing exported data. Once it's exported you can import it to Google Maps.